# How to extract and import Wikipedia pages?

Tags: php, xml, extract, mysql, wikipedia

I'm building a search engine, and to test it well, it needs more articles. Best source for them is Wikipedia.

I have searched for some dumps, but some are XML (which I am having troubles to import), some are not with content there.

So, how to get a dump, preferably in MySQL form. It has to be a non-English language.

Any idea?

Comment: can you give a little example for content's format?

Comment: if you had the sql dumps from wikipedia you would have a clone of wikipedia you'd need a the wiki software to get anything that starts to look like articles. There are apis available, and I would strongly suggest importing from either the api or one of the many structured data options that are available.

Comment: Err... are you sure that you have the resources to host a copy of Wikipedia? And even if you do, how do you plan to keep it updated?

Comment: @Eray doesn't matter, all I need to import to mysql some data so I can seach.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Get a life, no one asked that. I didn't ask for "do this job for me" but even if I do, you can just ignore that, so you don't have to tell everybody what are you. What if I had same experience, I have made a small script that does that and guess what, I have share it on my blog. I will tell people for that and help them.

Comment: @Mirzu & @thkala http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#Other_languages 

Like I said, I want some articles, even all, since they are not much in my language, and import them to mysql. I am not building wikipedia, I just want them for Search purpose to see how results are displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler) is a page explaining how to import Wikipedia to Solr.

[Here](http://blog.prashanthellina.com/2007/10/17/ways-to-process-and-use-wikipedia-dumps/) is a step-by-step explanation of loading a Wikipedia dump into Mysql to run a local clone.

Comment: +1 for a constructive answer. The OP just needs some test data, a perfectly valid thing to do

Comment: As it happens, I've been there, done that, and know that It's not so easy without a recipe.

Comment: At least there is a trail to follow :)